# Find <br/> tag inside <ins> </ins> tags and replace it

Tags: php, regex

For example I have:

```
<br/>
<ins>
<br/>
<br/>
</ins>
```

I want to find all `<br/>` between `<ins>` and `</ins>` tags and change them to: `<br/>&lt;br/&gt;`. This fix would allow my diff algorithm to actually make a line break and show that new line was inserted. Example now would look:

```
<br/>
<ins>
<br/>&lt;br/&gt;
<br/>&lt;br/&gt;
</ins>
```

I have no idea how to do this with PHP. I know it would require to use `preg_replace` or `preg_replace_callback`, but I have no knowledge of regex expressions to do it on my own.

Comment: regexes + html = make [Zalgo angry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068) use [DOM](http://php.net/dom) instead.

Comment: It may sound stupid, but DOM looks like an unnecessary work then you could write one line with preg_replace and forget about it.

Comment: and unless you can guarantee that the html you'll be regexing will NEVER be malformed/invalid, you'd be better off using a tool explicitly designed to handle html. Regexes are fine for the 99.9%, but you probably want 100%.

Comment: @stribizhev the code you wrote changes `<ins> <br/><br/> </ins>` into `<ins> <br> </ins>`

Comment: My bad, had to decode it. Works like a charm. And I think it is very safe way, because I purified html code before applying regex.

Comment: @stribizhev I was wondering how would regex look if I wanted to add `&lt;br/&gt` before `<br/>` but after `<ins>`? Intuitively I thought it should work with `&lt;br/&gt$0`, but in this case final result is `&lt;br/&gt<ins> <br/> </ins>`, it's outside `<ins>` tag.

Comment: @stribizhev I have tried rewriting code it to work if inside <ins> there are other tags: https://regex101.com/r/xI8mW9/4 It does find all tags inside <ins> but the problem is that it exits <ins> </ins> scope and keeps chaging <br/> after </ins> tag. Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PHP, (using logic)

```
<?php
$content = "<br/>
<ins>
<br/>
<br/>
</ins>
<ins>
<br/>
<br/>
</ins>
<br/>";

// Find all the positions from where <ins> is starting
$lastPos = 0;
$positions = array();
$count = 1;
while(($lastPos = strpos($content,"<ins>",$lastPos))!==false) {
    $positions[] = $lastPos;$lastPos=$lastPos+strlen("<ins>");
}
foreach($positions as $value) {
    ${"one".$count} = $value;$count++;
}

// Find all the positions from where </ins> is starting
$lastPos = 0;
$positions = array();
$count = 1;
while(($lastPos = strpos($content,"</ins>",$lastPos))!==false) {
    $positions[] = $lastPos;$lastPos=$lastPos+strlen("</ins>");
}
foreach($positions as $value) {
    ${"two".$count} = $value;$count++;
}

// Store the elements present inside all the <ins></ins> tags in PHP variables and replace <br/> with <br/>&lt;br/&gt;
for($i=1;$i<=$count-1;$i++)
{
    ${"area".$i} = substr($content,${"one".$i}+5,${"two".$i}-${"one".$i}-5);
    if(strpos(${"area".$i},"<br/>")) ${"area_new".$i} = str_replace("<br/>","<br/>&lt;br/&gt;",${"area".$i});
}

for($i=1;$i<=$count-1;$i++)
{
    $content = str_replace(${"area".$i},${"area_new".$i},$content);
}
// Now $content contains what you wanted it to be.
?>
```

or, (using predefined function)

```
<?php
$content = "<br/>
<ins>
<br/>
<br/>
</ins>
<ins>
<br/>
<br/>
</ins>
<br/>";
$content = preg_replace('~(?:<ins>|(?!^)\G)\s*<br\/>~', '$0&lt;br/&gt;', $content);
?>
```

Comment: Undefined variable: area_new1